# Play WS handshake_failure exception even with ws.acceptAnyCertificate = true

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using Play WS to download a file, but I get a `handshake_failure` exception, even with `ws.acceptAnyCertificate = true`.

```
// libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.5.15"
import akka.actor._
import akka.stream._
import akka.util.ByteString
import play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc._

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

implicit val system = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
val ws = AhcWSClient()

println(ws.config.isAcceptAnyCertificate) // false

def getBody(future: Future[WSResponse]): ByteString = {
  val response: WSResponse = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
  if (response.status != 200)
    throw new Exception(response.statusText)
  response.bodyAsBytes
}

def download(url: String): ByteString =
  HttpUtils.getBody(ws.url(url).withFollowRedirects(true).get())

download("https://www.tivo.com/legal/patents")
// Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

In a play application, I could create a file `conf/application.conf` with the text `ws.acceptAnyCertificate=true`. But I am using play-ws as a lib, not as an application. So I do as follows:

```
val loose = SSLLooseConfig(acceptAnyCertificate = true, allowWeakCiphers = true, allowWeakProtocols = true, allowUnsafeRenegotiation = Option(true))
val sslConfig = SSLConfig(loose = loose)
val wsClientConfig = WSClientConfig(ssl = sslConfig)
private val config = AhcWSClientConfig(wsClientConfig)
val ws = AhcWSClient(config)
println(ws.config.isAcceptAnyCertificate) // true
```

However, I still get the same exception:

```
download("https://www.tivo.com/legal/patents")
// Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

It works with download("https://www.epfl.ch/") but not with download("https://www.tivo.com/legal/patents")

How to solve this?